# std::set<K, C>::operator<(const std::set<K, C>&) is not using C() but std::less()

Tags: c++, set

cannot delete my own question, so overwrite it instead...

Comment: Is this something you're seeing empirically, or is this in the spec?

Comment: This does seem kind of weird

Comment: @templatetypedef it's described here, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/operator_cmp

Comment: @MattMcNabb I'm on that page, but I don't see any specific reference to `std::less` there.

Comment: I see the behaviour described in this question with GCC 4.9, and that does seem to match the spec.

Comment: @templatetypedef It's not actually using `std::less`, but `std::lexicographical_compare` -- still, that's not the specified comparer.

Comment: @hvd Can't `std::lexicographical_compare` take in a comparator?

Comment: @templatetypedef It can, but then `operator<` needs to pass on that comparator, and it doesn't seem to be doing so.

Comment: @hvd I can't think of any reason why it should not pass on the comparator

Comment: @MattMcNabb Well, the library is not doing it because the standard says it must not. C++11 [container.requirements.general]p12 defines `a < b` as `lexicographical_compare(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end())`. Of course, why the standard says it must not is a good question. I see no reason for that either.

Comment: @hvd: While I write my answer and tripple-check that I didn't overlook something obvious, you answer in a comment? ;-)

Comment: @Deduplicator Heh, I didn't think it really answered the question unless it also included why the standard says what it does, that's why I only posted it as a comment. :) But perhaps I shouldn't have, there's not really any more that we can know.

Comment: @hvd: My guess is writer's cramp. Or they ran out of paper.

Answer (score 3):

It's not actually a bug in the implementaton, though it is arguably one in the standard:

> 23.2.1 General container requirements *[container.requirements.general]*
>   13 Table 98 lists operations that are provided for some types of containers but not others. Those containers for which the listed operations are provided shall implement the semantics described in Table 98 unless otherwise stated.

The table contains:

> `a < b`
>   convertible to `bool`
>   `lexicographical_compare(a.begin(),a.end(),b.begin(),b.end())`
>   pre: < is defined for values of T. < is a total ordering relationship.
>   linear

While later sections specify that `std::set` provides comparison-operators, it unfortunately does not change the definition from the one given above.

As an aside, `std::lexicographical_compare` is not actually using `std::less`, but using `<` directly. Not that that is in any way significant.